# Large scheduler delay in Apache Spark tasks using deploy mode cluster

Tags: apache-spark, cluster-computing, scheduler

Using `spark-submit` command with `--master yarn --deploy-mode cluster` causes larger scheduler delays rather than using `--master yarn --deploy-mode client`.

Task performance results Screenshot:

[image]

This primarily concerns jobs with `collect` operation called on RDDs.

The spark application started in `client` mode takes approximately 3 - 4 minutes, on the contrary to `cluster` mode with 6 - 7 minutes. The size of each task within stages is less than 100 KB. Cluster has 8 data nodes and runs Cloudera Manager 5.9.0

Comment: does data nodes have less available memory than driver (client)?

Comment: Each data node has 48GB of memory and a name node has 64GB. In a client mode driver runs on a name node, and in a cluster mode on one of the data nodes. In both modes each executor gets 2GB of memory and driver 4GB. I have also experimented by setting other values for memory, but it doesn't provide better results in scheduler delays.

Comment: Did you find the reason why that would happen?

Answer (score 1):

The solution for this particular case. The problem was caused by the broken ethernet cable in the cluster infrastructure. After replacing it the time has reduced greatly.